# How to make ValidatesOnDataErrors bindable?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, mvvm

I have to need to bind the value of `ValidatesOnDataErrors`, so that it can be determined at run-time.

The reason for this, is because i don't always want to validate the data.

This is a property of a binding so i know i **CANT** do this:

```
"{Binding Path=SomePath, ValidatesOnDataErrors={Binding Path=SomeBoolProperty}}"
```

So my question is, how would i change my binding so that the value of `ValidatesOnDataErrors`, can be determined at run-time.

**NOTE:** I want to keep the binding in the `ViewModel`. I don't want to set anything in the `View's` code behind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement this logic inside your ViewModel, and make it implement the IDataErrorInfo interface.

When no validation is required, make the properties :

```
string Error { get; }
string this[string columnName] { get; }
```

return an empty string;

As a bonus, this behavior will be easily testable.